# Trying to access a bash array via function results in ${1[@]}: bad substitution

Tags: arrays, bash, function

There's not much to say but the code below results in bad substitution.

```
#!/bin/bash

numbers=(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
charslc=(a b c d e f g h i j)
charsuc=(A B C D E F G H I J)

show () {
        # value of var is now held in $1
        for i in "${1[@]}"; do
         echo $i
        done
}

#
# some processing happens here resulting in
# var=numbers OR
# var=charslc OR
# var=charsuc
#

var=numbers # simulating the process mentioned above
show $var
```

Question: How can this be fixed while ideally sticking to this type of approach?

Comment: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays#indirection

Answer (score 3):

Define your function as:

```
show() {
   arr=$1[@]
   for i in "${!arr}"; do
      echo "$i"
   done
}
```

And call it as:

```
numbers=(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
var=numbers
show "$var"
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done a bit more simply:

Call script:

```
./myscript.sh "a b c"
```

Script contains:

```
for i in $1
do
    echo $i
done
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
```